# Node.js localhost:3000 refuses to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, localhost

I am a total beginner of Node.js and I am unable to connect to localhost:3000

I use the following code in VS code, hit "node app.js" in terminal, and there is no error comes out in terminal at this point.
However, as I try to access the localhost:3000, it keeps refusing: "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
I searched on the internet for solutions and tried opening ports by creating an inbound rule on security settings, turned IIS on, used 127.0.0.1 instead, and still get refused. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

I am using Windows 10

---

```
const http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(
    (request, response)=>{
        response.end('hello');
    }
);

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: does it work with Port 80?

Comment: Is there any output from the program at all? Or is it silent? If it's silent try adding some logging calls to check that the program is actually being executed

Comment: @MRonline No. When I do so and browse http://localhost:80, it directs me to the localhost default page saying "Internet Information Service"

Comment: @MickelsonMichael Thank you for mentioning it. Actually it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Somehow it work after I hit Run → "Run and Debug" and then enter "node app.js" in the terminal. That is not a step instructed in my textbook, but is that what I always should be doing when launching a server?

Comment: Omg, I realized this was not even about run and debug.
Seems like all I had to do was Shift + S and save the file before running it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to fix it. Your probably try to launch your server on a used port.

```js
// enter this command in your terminal
lsof -i:3000

// this will output the related PID (process ID). Here: 1382.
node      1382 name   21u  IPv6 blabla      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)

// kill the PID in use
kill -9 1382

//relaunch your server
node app.js
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When try howver, it says "lsof is not recognized"

Comment: Aa, maybe lsof command is not available on windows. Please try `netstat -a -n -o | find "3000"` . You should get the pid with this command.

Comment: Wonderful! This works! Good to know this command to check and open(?) ports.

Comment: Cool! Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

I ran it on my computer and that code works fine. I would try other ports to see if they work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using 8080, 3001 but they don't work either.